# Bash negative wildcard using sub shell with `bash -c`

Tags: bash, glob

In bash, I can use a negative wildcard to glob all files in a directory that don't match some pattern, for example:

```
echo src/main/webapp/!(WEB-INF)
```

This works fine.

However, if I try to use exactly the same wildcard with `bash -c` to pass the command as an argument to a new bash shell, I get a syntax error:

```
$ bash -c 'echo src/main/webapp/!(WEB-INF)'
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `echo src/main/webapp/!(WEB-INF)'
```

Note that if I use a different glob, like `bash -c 'echo src/main/webapp/*'` it works as expected.

Why doesn't bash accept the same negative glob with `-c` as it does when run normally, and how can I get it to accept this negative glob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `!(..)` is a extended glob pattern that is turned on by default in your interactive bash shell, but in an explicit sub-shell launched with `-c`, the option is turned off. You can see that

```
$ shopt | grep extglob
extglob         on
$ bash -c 'shopt | grep extglob'
extglob         off
```

One way to turn on the option explicitly in command line would be to use the `-O` flag followed by the option to be turned on

```
$ bash -O extglob -c 'shopt | grep extglob'
extglob         on
```

See [extglob on Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) for the list of extended glob patterns supported and [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) for a list of the extended shell options and which ones are enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

It happens the feature at stake is only enabled by default in an interactive shell. In bash, this is controlled by the [`extglob` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

> **extglob**
>
> If set, the extended pattern matching features described above (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)) are enabled.

To confirm this, you can run for example:

```
$ bash -c 'shopt -p | grep extglob'
shopt -u extglob

$ bash -i -c 'shopt -p | grep extglob'
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: You don't have to use `-i`, just turn on the flags needed directly